# Collections's BinarySearch isn't working

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, binary-search

I am new to JAVA and Netbeans and this is what I have to do:
The user can enter a title CD in the input box and then remove the CD from the list by pressing the remove button. If the CD does not exist in the collection, then a message can be displayed in the outbox to state this.
This is what I have done:

```
ArrayList <String> songs = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(songs, "Metric - Fantasies", "\nBeatles - Abbey Road", "\nPearl Jam - Ten", "\nDoors - Alive", "\nThe Rolling Stones - Gimme Shelter\n");
int remove = Collections.binarySearch(songs, artistinput.getText());
    if (remove < 0)
    {
        output.setText("That CD does not exist in the collection, please try again");
    }
    else if (remove >= 0)
    {
        boolean delete=songs.remove(artistinput.getText());{
    output.setText("Original Songs \n" +delete);
```

This is the only part of the program that I havent figured out. This does not work as it only displays  `output.setText("That CD does not exist in the collection, please try again");` every time I type the song and press 'remove'. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!!

Comment: Your songs is not sorted. And it contains newline characters `\n`, why? Also, is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835111/difficulty-with-collections-binarysearch/40835224?noredirect=1#comment68887977_40835224) you?

Comment: It's not likely you'll get text with `\n` from your input, Doctor.

Comment: thats not me even though our questions are kinda same

Answer (score 0):

With java 8, you can try this way :

```
    List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    int size = songs.size();
    Collections.addAll(songs, "Metric - Fantasies", "\nBeatles - Abbey Road", "\nPearl Jam - Ten", "\nDoors - Alive", "\nThe Rolling Stones - Gimme Shelter\n");
    songs.removeIf(o->o.equalsIgnoreCase(artistinput.getText()));
    int arSize = songs.size();
    if(size != arSize){
        System.out.println("Original Songs \\n" + (size-arSize));
    }else System.out.println("That CD does not exist in the collection, please try again");
```

Answer (score 0):

In order use `binarysearch` you have to ensure the array is **ordered**. You havent sort your `songs` so you dont get your expected result. And I dont know why you add `\n` for your song name.

---

An alternative solution is sort your array first. AS below:

```
    ArrayList <String> songs = new ArrayList();
    Collections.addAll(songs, "Metric - Fantasies", "\nBeatles - Abbey Road", "\nPearl Jam - Ten", "\nDoors - Alive", "\nThe Rolling Stones - Gimme Shelter\n");
    Collections.sort(songs);//////sort the songs
   int remove = Collections.binarySearch(songs, artistinput.getText());
   if (remove < 0)
   {
        output.setText("That CD does not exist in the collection, please try again");
   }
  else if (remove >= 0)
  {
       boolean delete=songs.remove(artistinput.getText());{
       output.setText("Original Songs \n" +delete);
  }
```

Comment: added \n so it displays on new line because I am using textfield and does not display it on new line. So, that is what my teacher suggested me to do

Answer (score 0):

Simple quick way to do it. I changed your input and output system around but I'm guessing thats fine for your class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dumbshit{

public static void main(String args[]){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
songs.add("Metric - Fantasies");
songs.add("Beatles - Abbey Road");
songs.add("Pearl Jam - Ten");
//etc
//this can obviously be done better
Collections.sort(songs);
int index = Collections.binarySearch(songs, scan.nextLine());
    if (index < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("That CD does not exist in the collection, please try again");
    }
    else if (index >= 0)
    {
        songs.remove(index);
        for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++){
            System.out.println( songs.get(i) );
        }
    }
 }
}
```